# git reports that submodule has changes even if it does not

Tags: git

I have git repository where I have several submodules. I have fetched latest commit in main git repo. But If I type `git checkout origin/master` then I got error because of changes in submodules that should be commited first. In main repo `git status` shows that there are changes in submodules. But `git status` in each submodule shows no changes. When Issue `git diff some_submodule` from main repo there are changes which only shows changing of commit ID:

```
diff --git a/some_submoduleb/some_submodule
index 21c00cb..2392944 160000
--- a/some_submodule
+++ b/some_submodule
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 21c00cb4729feacd95a9ea01d100a2e0f2ddb604
+Subproject commit 2392944290df7d41ad3abfe50f71e5c3886de798
```

Why is this happening and how can checkout `origin/master` in main repo?

Config:

- OS: Ubuntu
- git version: 2.17.1

Comment: What commits do the IDs correspond to?

Comment: 2392944290df7d41ad3abfe50f71e5c3886de798 is latest commit 21c00cb4729feacd95a9ea01d100a2e0f2ddb604 is older one. Why is it important?

Answer (score 0):

The submodule changed and the change must be committed in the superproject repository:

```
git add some_submodule
git commit -m "Update some_submodule"
```

Now you can continue with `git checkout`.

If you don't want to commit — revert the change:

```
git submodule update some_submodule
```

`git` checks out the saved commit in the submodule.

Comment: How colud submodule changed if `git status` in submodule dsubdirectory does not report any changes?

Comment: There is a change in the submodule — its `HEAD` now points to a different commit. The superproject remembers all the current commits in all submodules hence it considers this a change that should be either reverted (`git submodule update some_submodule`) or committed.

Answer (score 0):

The repository where you have added the submodule points to a specific commit in the history of the submodule. Commiting changes inside the submodule does not change the commit pointed to by the outer repository.

It might help to think of this as a version of a library, for example. When you commit changes inside the submodule you are creating a new version, but the outer repository still points to the old version as a dependency. If you want to change the version you depend on, you need to change the outer repository as well.

`git status` is telling you that your local submodule is pointing to `commit 2392944` but the upstream is pointing to `commit 21c00cb`. If your repository should be using `commit 2392944` of the submodule, then you must commit this change in the outer repository (the only thing this commit will do is point to the new commit, it won't change anything inside the submodule).

Comment: I do not want to commit anything new. I just want to checkout `origin/master` and get appropriate "versions" of submodules as they are pointed in `origin/master` commit.